# How to save image from clipboard to file in UWP

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp

Is there any equivalent of

```
Clipboard.GetImage().Save(FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

for UWP (Windows Universal Platform)?
I.e. saving the graphics image from clipboard into jpg format to file.

I am looking for example in vb.net/C#.

I have already started with

```
Dim datapackage = DataTransfer.Clipboard.GetContent()
If datapackage.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap) Then
Dim r As Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference = Await datapackage.GetBitmapAsync()
```

...

but I do not know how to continue (and even if I have even started correctly).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first step is to try and get the image from the clipboard, if it exists:

```
var dataPackageView = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.GetContent();
if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap))
{
    IRandomAccessStreamReference imageReceived = null;
    try
    {
        imageReceived = await dataPackageView.GetBitmapAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

If it exists, launch a file save picker, choose where to save the image, and copy the image stream to the new file.

```
    if (imageReceived != null)
    {
        using (var imageStream = await imageReceived.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            var fileSave = new FileSavePicker();
            fileSave.FileTypeChoices.Add("Image", new string[] { ".jpg" });
            var storageFile = await fileSave.PickSaveFileAsync();

            using (var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                await imageStream.AsStreamForRead().CopyToAsync(stream.AsStreamForWrite());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks good. And I like also that my 3 lines were OK, I mean good start (with exception of missing try/catch). jiri tywoniak

Comment: Note that though you have given the file a .jpg extension, it is still a BMP file. You need to convert the actual pixel data to save as JPG, PNG, etc.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Thank you for the great piece of advice. That saved a huge trouble for me.